# Passing "this" pointer to object constructor

Tags: c++, oop

I'm new to OOP in C++, and I'm struggling with (in my opinion) pretty simple thing.
Here is my code:

Player.h

```
class Player
{
private:
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sf::Texture texture;

public:
    Player(Game &game);
    virtual ~Player();

    void update();
    void render(sf::RenderTarget& target);
};
```

Player.cpp

```
Player::Player(Game& game)
{
    // doing some stuff with game object...

}

Player::~Player()
{
}

void Player::update()
{
}

void Player::render(sf::RenderTarget& target)
{
    target.draw(this->sprite);
}
```

Game.cpp

```
Game::Game(int width, int height)
{
    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;
    this->initializeWindow();
    this->player = new Player(*this);

}
```

I want to pass reference of Game object to Player object, however I get error stack like this:
[image]

Is there any simple solution for my problem?

Comment: Where is your definition of `Game`?

Comment: Add a forward declaration to Game in the player.h

Comment: Does Game.cpp have `#include "Player.h"` or some other way of seeing the definition of `Player`?

Comment: You should look at the very **first** error output by the compiler and figure out what file and line it is happening on.  Fix it, then repeat until you have no more errors.  It's kind of hard to help since you cropped out the file/line numbers and you have a lot of errors.  Make sure there is a definition of the Game class, or at least a forward declaration (`class Game;`) *before* any place you use `Game`.

Comment: You are not telling us the whole story. There is no `Player::Player(const Player&)` in your code. Also, as @DavidGrayson says, GIVE US THE LINE NUMBERS!

Comment: Side note: The Error list is an executive summary of the detected problems in your code. Not far from the Error List tab you should find the Output tab. In the output tab you'll find the full and unadulterated error messages as text, perfect for pasting into a Stack Overflow question, and the extra information in the full error diagnostics often solves the problem before it starts. It's long and often intimidating, but I don't think I've looked at the Error List in years.

Comment: And line numbers are for the weak. Give us a [mre], assuming that making the [mre] doesn't lead you to the solution. It usually does.

Comment: @TonyK "*There is no `Player::Player(const Player&)` in your code*" - it is clear that because of the 1st error on `Player(Game &game)`, the compiler creates a *side effect* that it then thinks `new Player(*this)` is trying to call the **implicitly-generated** `Player(const Player&)` copy constructor instead, and thus fails with a mismatch.  Fix the original error, and the side effect disappears.

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular reference issue. `Game` has a `Player*` member, so it needs to know that `Player` exists. And `Player`'s constructor has a `Game&` parameter, so it needs to know that `Game` exists.

Since `Game` uses `Player` by pointer, `Game.h` only needs to know that `Player` exists, not what the full `Player` class looks like.  Only `Game.cpp` needs to know what `Player` actually looks like in order to access its members.

Since `Player` uses `Game` by reference, `Player.h` only needs to know that `Game` exists, not what the full `Game` class looks like.  Only `Player.cpp` needs to know what `Game` actually looks like in order to access its members.

So, to solve this, you can use [**forward declarations**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Forward_declaration) in the `.h` files, and `#include` statements in the `.cpp` files, eg:

Player.h

```cpp
class Game; // <--

class Player
{
private:
    ...

public:
    Player(Game &game);
    ...
};
```

Player.cpp

```cpp
#include "Game.h" // <--

Player::Player(Game& game)
{
    // doing some stuff with game object...
}

...
```

Game.h

```cpp
class Player; // <--

class Game
{
private:
    int width;
    int height;
    Player *player;

    void initializeWindow();
    ...

public:
    Game(int width, int height);
    ~Game();
    ...
};
```

Game.cpp

```cpp
#include "Player.h" // <--

Game::Game(int width, int height)
    : width(width), height(height)
{
    initializeWindow();
    player = new Player(*this);
}

Game::~Game()
{
    delete player;
}

void Game::initializeWindow()
{
    ...
}

...
```